# Create and access sqlite3 database using python3

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to create (and later, access) a database using python3.
From millions of example in SO and internet([eg. this](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y115/sqlite.py)), I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from string import ascii_uppercase
import sqlite3
sqlfile = "jour.db"
tabname = "abbre"
id_col  = "Full_Name"
col_name = "Abbre_name"

conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlfile)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Journals
          (jid int, full text , abbr text)''')
c.execute("""insert into Journals values (1, 'Physical Review B', 'Phys. Rev. B')""")

conn.commit()
c.close()
```

But, it is creating the table, but no data is inserted.

What is going wrong here?[image: This is the output of the database]

Answer (score -1):

You are looking at the wrong database file. (The schema is different.)

Connecting to the file name `jour.db` will use the current directory, whatever that happens to be.
The correct `jour.db` database file is *somewhere* on your computer.

It might be a good idea to specify the full path of the database file.

Comment: I was looking at the current directory only. I have sorted the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

comparing your insert function to a tutorial I saw it seems very off

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
      VALUES (4, 'Mark', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 )");
```

so I am thinking you need it to be more like

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Journals (jid, full, abbr) \
      VALUES (1, 'Physical Review B', 'Phys. Rev. B')");
```

Comment: I am going to try your suggestion, but, see this: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: hmm if that formatting works then it must be that you included 3 pairs of quotation marks.
your code:
c.execute("""insert into Journals values (1, 'Physical Review B', 'Phys. Rev. B')""")

Comment: their code:
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")